# How to mute the videoview when it's playing

Tags: android, video

I am searching for a long time on net, and many answers advised to use the **setVolume** in **MediaPlayer.OnPreParedListener**, it works when I use it before **MediaPlayer.start()**.
But now there is a button, I want to control  mute or unmute when the video **is playing**, so how to resolve it?

Comment: in the OnPreparedListener, you can save MediaPlayer to a variable, and then when you need it, you can call `setVolume` on it

Comment: @VladMatvienko Oh, thank you for your help! It solves my problem

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

private static int aux = 0;

```
private Button mMuteButton;
private static int aux = 0;
private AudioManager mAudioManager;
```

//set the Mute button on clickListener  inside the class android cycle where needed

```
mMuteButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

            if(aux % 2 == 0){

                mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100, 0);
                aux++;


            } else {

                mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0, 0);
                aux++;

            }


        }
    });
```

Comment: @user7145445 Were u able to try

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But there has other audio that I don't want it mute. Using the AudioManager will close the system volume so that all the      audio will mute, but I only want to mute the video! Thank yout!